# Definition of an algebra

Tags: measure-theory

The definition of an algebra says that given a set X, an algebra of subsets of X is a collection $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of X such that:
if $A \in \mathcal{A}$ then $A^c \in \mathcal{A}$
My question is if it is correct to say that if $A \notin \mathcal{A}$ then $A^c \notin \mathcal{A}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the statement
$$A\in \mathcal{A} \implies A^c\in \mathcal{A}$$
immediately implies that the converse holds since $(A^c)^c=A$. Namely, one has
$$A^c\in \mathcal{A}\implies (A^c)^c=A\in \mathcal{A}. \tag{$\ast$}$$
The contrapositive statement of $(\ast)$ is what you want to prove to be true.